# escape a <token> in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

so I have this problem. I'm working with a framework that takes a stored procedure and creates sql from it. The resulting sql has these "tokens" that are replaced by the framework. 
simple eg:

```
declare @sql as varchar(max)

set @sql = '              
select * from table where <token>
   '
select @sql
```

this stored proc gets called from the front end with exec and I cannot parameterize it (limitation).

this would then be parsed in the framework and the token replaced with values from the front end into something like this:

```
select * from table where ((table.id = '1112'))
```

I do not have access to the  variable in any other place than in the stored procedure before it's transformed.  the above works great for specifying a filter but Now I need to get the '1112' as text to be used in a column name later on in my procedure. 
I kind of need to do something like this:
    set @myToken = ' '< token>' '

then parse @myToken for the id or whatever is after the = sign.

the problem is, I don't know how to escape the token beforehand so i could manipulate it with, say a substring function for example, to strip out the value. it breaks because of the single quotes. 
The sql generated from the above would be:

```
set @myToken = '(table.id = '1112')'
```

which obviously breaks it. I'm leaning towards this can't be done but I'd love for someone to confirm it or offer some advice. Thanks!

Comment: It is no general solution but can't you resort to non-string literals in your case? In the vein of `table.id = cast(1112 to varchar(4))`?

Comment: I wish I could, but unfortunately I cannot, I literally only have access to / can use the '<token>' literal. i'll chalk this one up as not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but have you tried turning quoted identifiers off?
This should allow you to surround your `<token>` in double quotes to set it as a variable.

```
  DECLARE @MyToken VARCHAR(MAX)
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
--SET @MyToken = "<MyToken>"
  SET @MyToken = "'(table.id = '1112')'"
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  SELECT @MyToken
```

Comment: Thanks Troy, that was one of the last things I tried :) it didn't work, but what I didn't do is set it back on before the select! I'll give that try see if it changes anything.